# WEBブラウザゲームのデータベース設計について

Tags: postgresql, database

現在、以下のページのようなWEBブラウザゲームを作成しています。
http://strawberry-magic.com/play.html
シーン内にレンガや、敵キャラを配置することで自分でステージを作っていくゲームです。
RPGツクールやMinecraft、マリオメーカーのような方向性を目指しています。

今後、サイト内にユーザー認証機能を実装して、データベースと接続することで
ユーザーごとに作ったステージを保存できるようにしたいと思っています。

そこで、データベース設計の壁にぶつかっています。
このようなゲームの場合、ステージが何十個、何百個も作られることになると思うのですが
ステージ内のアイテムの情報も何百、何千と膨大になるかと思います。
こういった場合、1つのステージごとにデータベースのテーブルを1つ作るのか
それとも複数のステージの情報を1つのデータベースのテーブルの中に入れてしまうのが良いのか
どちらなのでしょうか？それとも全く別のアプローチが良いのでしょうか？

使用しているデータベースはPostgreSQLで
sequelizeやNodeJSと組み合わせて使用するつもりでいます。

設計しようと思っているテーブルは以下のような形です。
ステージ内の全ピクセルに対して01010111100といった形で情報を埋め込むと
データ量が多くなりすぎるかと思ったので
ステージ内に配置した敵キャラクターの位置情報やブロックの位置情報は
配列の奇数ケタにx座標、配列の偶数ケタにy座標、というように入れていこうかと思っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: それぞれの具体的なテーブル定義のサンプルを追記してもらえますか？

Comment: 「1つのステージごとにデータベースのテーブルを1つ作るのか
それとも複数のステージの情報を1つのデータベースのテーブルの中に入れてしまう」と質問には書かれていますが追記されたのはどちらか一方だけに見えます。あと「ステージ」＝「シーン」ですか?ちがう物なのですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ステージごとに根本的な違いがあるなら別テーブルでもいいと思いますが
ただステージ数が違うというだけであれば、グループ項目等を設けてまとまりで取得できるような構造にしておけば、ステージテーブルとしては１つで良いのではないかと思います。

別の方法としては、もう全部JSONで持ってしまうとかですかね？

Answer (score 0):

postgresqlを使っているなら、ステージ情報を varbit や varchar で持つのがいいと思います

varbit は varchar よりもDBの容量的に得ですが、DB から値を引き出すときに 0/1 の文字が送られてしまうことが多いので、通信帯域的には損するかもしれません

varbit は ORM mapper など、ライブラリとの相性が悪そうなので、そこも検討材料になると思います

---

いずれにせよ

空気 = 00000000
自機 = 00000001
レンガ = 00000002
...

のように各ブロックに1つの値を割り当て、それらを連結したものを保存する、という方針をとるのが一般的ではないでしょうか